# How to produce such webpage like https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898

Tags: pdf, web-development, html, html-editor, plain-text

The [IETF site](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) has some nice properties:

- Links from the HTML version to the TXT and the PDF versions
- Links to sections, other documents
- Format for PDF, HTML and TXT nearly identical
- Page numbers, authors name
- Subsequence versions that obsolete a document

I'm thinking about using building our internal document system base on the
format of IETF (not sure that other people will like that, or it's me). But I
don't know which tools and document to use.

What are the tools involved to build such sites:

- Editor
- Document format/syntax: that not markdown, man page… Look like vim help, but they are not the same, consider the footer and header
- HTML renderer and linker
- PDF renderer and linker

Comment: View the page source of an RFC and you see in the meta tags... _creator_ [rfcmarkup version 1.126](https://tools.ietf.org/tools/rfcmarkup/) - that would seem to be just a small part of it, but maybe a start?